# Angular2 Kendo ui drag and drop

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I been trying to implement a drag and drop feature in kendo-grid for angular2 to change the order of the columns within a grid.

I noticed there's a kendo-sortable for drag and drop, but I'm failing to see how I can implement the kendo-grid with this feature.

Comment: to sort on grids, you use the grid sortable property, not the kendo-sortable

Comment: the sortable property does that, sort, the collumn, but what i want is to change the order of the collumns.

Comment: i dont think that you can

Comment: thanks, i know you could do it in older versions of the kendo, for the jquery and angular 1.x versions, so i had my hopes up for something similar the new kendo version.

Comment: they'll probably implement it eventually but from what i know, that isnt possibly (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do this http://plnkr.co/edit/ehL52SiMkLBGb34sC8Dd?p=preview

The column chooser component is using the `SortableComponent` and allows you to reorder column, which are reflected in the Grid.